# Unexpected indent when using save function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a readfile.csv file have the struction as

```
E:\\Project_Face\\Projects\\arnold_schwarzenegger_01.jpg;1
E:\\Project_Face\\Projects\\arnold_schwarzenegger_02.jpg;1
E:\\Project_Face\\Projects\\emma_watson_01.jpg;0
```

I used the python to extract the path and lable (such as 0 and 1). Path and lable are separated by semicolon. I used a sample code to extract path of file ,rename it and save in other folder . However, I have the error as the below. 
[image]
When I replace the path in the save function (`save("_10_10_200_200.jpg")`). it work well . However, it had error if I use a the other path such as.

```
save(".\\modified\\"+img.rstrip().split('\\')[5]+"_10_10_200_200.jpg")
```

**Could you help me to fix it?** Thank in advance. This is python code

```
import sys, math, Image
import os
from __future__ import print_function

def Distance(p1,p2):
  dx = p2[0] - p1[0]
  dy = p2[1] - p1[1]
  return math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)

def ScaleRotateTranslate(image, angle, center = None, new_center = None, scale = None, resample=Image.BICUBIC):
  if (scale is None) and (center is None):
    return image.rotate(angle=angle, resample=resample)
  nx,ny = x,y = center
  sx=sy=1.0
  if new_center:
    (nx,ny) = new_center
  if scale:
    (sx,sy) = (scale, scale)
  cosine = math.cos(angle)
  sine = math.sin(angle)
  a = cosine/sx
  b = sine/sx
  c = x-nx*a-ny*b
  d = -sine/sy
  e = cosine/sy
  f = y-nx*d-ny*e
  return image.transform(image.size, Image.AFFINE, (a,b,c,d,e,f), resample=resample)

def CropFace(image, eye_left=(0,0), eye_right=(0,0), offset_pct=(0.2,0.2), dest_sz = (70,70)):
  # calculate offsets in original image
  offset_h = math.floor(float(offset_pct[0])*dest_sz[0])
  offset_v = math.floor(float(offset_pct[1])*dest_sz[1])
  # get the direction
  eye_direction = (eye_right[0] - eye_left[0], eye_right[1] - eye_left[1])
  # calc rotation angle in radians
  rotation = -math.atan2(float(eye_direction[1]),float(eye_direction[0]))
  # distance between them
  dist = Distance(eye_left, eye_right)
  # calculate the reference eye-width
  reference = dest_sz[0] - 2.0*offset_h
  # scale factor
  scale = float(dist)/float(reference)
  # rotate original around the left eye
  image = ScaleRotateTranslate(image, center=eye_left, angle=rotation)
  # crop the rotated image
  crop_xy = (eye_left[0] - scale*offset_h, eye_left[1] - scale*offset_v)
  crop_size = (dest_sz[0]*scale, dest_sz[1]*scale)
  image = image.crop((int(crop_xy[0]), int(crop_xy[1]), int(crop_xy[0]+crop_size[0]), int(crop_xy[1]+crop_size[1])))
  # resize it
  image = image.resize(dest_sz, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  return image

def readFileNames():
    try:
        inFile = open('E:\\Project_Face\\Projects\\image_data.csv')
    except:
        raise IOError('There is no file named path_to_created_csv_file.csv in current directory.')
        return False

    picPath = []
    picIndex = []
    for line in inFile.readlines():
        if line != '':

            fields = line.rstrip().split(';')
            picPath.append(fields[0])
            picIndex.append(int(fields[1]))

    return (picPath, picIndex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  [images, indexes]=readFileNames()
if not os.path.exists("modified"):
    os.makedirs("modified")
for img in images:
    image =  Image.open(img)
    CropFace(image, eye_left=(182,264), eye_right=(304,265), offset_pct=(0.1,0.1), dest_sz=(200,200)).save(".\\modified\\"+img.rstrip().split('\\')[5]+"_10_10_200_200.jpg")
   CropFace(image, eye_left=(182,264), eye_right=(304,265), offset_pct=(0.2,0.2), dest_sz=(200,200)).save(".\\modified\\"+img.rstrip().split('\\')[5]+"_20_20_200_200.jpg")
   CropFace(image, eye_left=(182,264), eye_right=(304,265), offset_pct=(0.3,0.3), dest_sz=(200,200)).save(".\\modified\\"+img.rstrip().split('\\')[5]+"_30_30_200_200.jpg")
  CropFace(image, eye_left=(182,264), eye_right=(304,265), offset_pct=(0.2,0.2)).save("_20_20_70_70.jpg").save(".\\modified\\"+img.rstrip().split('\\')[5]+"_20_20_70_70.jpg")
```

Comment: Your line indentation for the `CropFace(image, eye_left=...` lines are not the same. Also, some of the lines appear to be indented with two spaces and some appear to be indented with four; I would recommend you pick onr indentation level and stick with it. Four spaces is always a good choice as it fits normal Python convention.

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` must be at the beginning of the file because it's not an ordinary import, but a compatibility switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got errors like:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

It means that you have too few or too many spaces in the beginning of the line.

For example, this is wrong:

```
a = 1
b = 2
 c = a + b  # must be aligned with previous lines
```

And this is wrong too:

```
if c == 3:
    print('Hello world!')  # 4 spaces relative to "if" - ok
   print('Needs one more space')  # 3 spaces - error
```

Generally, Python code should be written with 4 spaces indentation at each level, according to [PEP-8 coding standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @john2182 You have updated your question to somethin completely else. Have a look at this QA pair: do you think a future reader will understand that? Probably not. So please start a new question for your new problem instead of updating the old one.

Comment: @john2182 Oh, and pleaser prefer posting text instead of an image. That's much better readable.

Comment: @john2182 If original question is solved and you got stuck at another problem, please create a separate question (of course, after spending at least 10 minutes trying to solve it yourself :-))

Comment: It is original problem. It is saving data problem in python. I did not resolve it. Thank it

Comment: @john2182: No, it's a different problem. The same thing is broken, but in an entirely different way.

Comment: What is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'. Note that the CropFace return the image type

Comment: @john2182 Your question was specifically about "Unexpected indent", so editing it into "oh, and now this and that doesn't work" will only confuse people who may stumble upon the same problem in the future. Please be specific, or you'll be downvoted. One error - one question. Different error - different question. And please, show some effort. Stackoverflow is helpful, but it won't do your work for you.